# Postgres JSONB support on zend/Db Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-db, jsonb, zend-framework3

how can i work with JSONB (postgresql) in zend framework 3?.

for example i want make query's like this

```
SELECT id, data->'title' AS title, data->'description' as description FROM tablename

SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'tags') as tag FROM tablename WHERE id = 1;
```

Or EXECUTE a function like a

```
SELECT myFunction()


jsonb_each(jsonb)


INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (1,'{"title": "title 1","category":"category 2"}')


UPDATE tablename SET data = jsonb_set(data,'{"image","quality"}','{" copyright":"company X","registered":true}') where id=2;
```

ETC.

**I have a model and only get the id value**

```
<?php
namespace EntityModel\Model;

class Entity
{
    public $idEntity;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $access;
    public $category;
    public $isVisible;
    public $urlProyect;
    public $urlDownload;
    public $pedagogicUse;
    public $PublicatorUser;
    /**
     * [exchangeArray description]
     * @param  array  $data [description]
     * @return [type]       [description]
     */
    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->id     = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->title = !empty($data['title']) ? $data['title'] : null;
        $this->description  = !empty($data['description']) ? $data['description'] : null;
        $this->access = !empty($data['access']) ? $data['access'] : null;
        $this->category = !empty($data['category']) ? $data['category'] : null;
        $this->isVisible = !empty($data['isvisible']) ? $data['isvisible'] : null;
        $this->urlProyect = !empty($data['urlproyect']) ? $data['urlproyect'] : null;
        $this->urlDownload = !empty($data['urldownload']) ? $data['urldownload'] : null;
        $this->PedagogicUse = !empty($data['pedagogicUse']) ? $data['pedagogicUse'] : null;
        $this->publicatorUser = !empty($data['publicatoruser']) ? $data['publicatoruser'] : null;
    }
}
```

I want to return the jsonb object in the exchangeArray method like id=>4,title=>"title"

How can i implement this ideas, i follow the tutotial from ZF3 and i don't know how implement, maybe here is not the place for this question, but i appreciate if you give me a feedback, i don´t want to use ORM for this project. Thanks

This is the model file we can make a query with this methods

```
class EntityTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;
    protected $dbAdapter;
    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        $this->dbAdapter = $tableGateway->adapter;
    }

public function getAllFromQuery()
{
     $query = $this->dbAdapter->query("SELECT count(*) FROM tablename WHERE data ? 'isVisible';", Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
        $data = $query->toArray();

        return $data;
    }
```

**it´s important than you have declare in your db adapter**

```
'db' => [
        'driver' => 'Pgsql',  // pdo not support all the pg_ functions
        'database' => 'database',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass'
    ]
```

**In a Action call**

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        return new ViewModel([
            'data' =>$this->table->getAllFromQuery()
        ]);
    }
```

and the view

```
<?= var_dump($this->data) ?>
```

**AND THE RESULT IS THAT**

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> string(1) "6" } }
```

Well this is a want to take from the data base but, how can i pass the data array into a entity exchangeArray method??

**i get it!!**

```
public function getAllFromQuery()
    {
        $query = $this->dbAdapter->createStatement("SELECT id,
                                                data->>'title' as title,
                                                data->>'acess' as access,
                                                data->>'category' as category
                                                FROM tablename");
        $data= $query->execute();
        /* OR if you want execute a function from postgres */

        //$query = $this->dbAdapter->query("SELECT totalregistrosdinamico('tablename')", Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->initialize($data);
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\EntityName());
        return $resultSetPrototype;

    }
```